# spring boot run on both windows and linux

Tags: spring-boot

I need to run my app on both windows and linux. I started with linux and used spring boot.

I run it simply with:

```
nohup java -jar ..... &
```

and I can easily tail the nohup log file.

I can find and kill the process easily too.

How can I do that in windows?

Thanks,
id

Comment: Do you mean you want to run it as a background process?

Comment: yes... including out logs and the option to kill the porcess. Im not a windows guy..

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 1.3 (about to be released) has many improvements in that area; there is a service support for Unix and Windows.

Check [the updated documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-install)